# Using WebExecute to automatically download data

Tags: web-access

With WebExcute, I have been able to get access to a particular url https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx

However, in this url, there is a quite a number of stock code that one can select and then click to download the data. For example, to pick the stock code of (00700) Tencent and download the associated data.

My question is what will be the command to perform the above steps.

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

To get the list of codes and company names

```
WebExecute[session, "ElementText" -> #] & /@ 
 WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "Tag" -> "option"]
```

> {(00001) CKH Holdings,(00002) CLP,(00003) HK & China Gas,(00004)
>   Wharf,(00005) HSBC,(00006) Power Assets,(00011) Hang Seng Bank,(00012)
>   Henderson Land,(00016) SHK Properties,(00017) New World Dev,(00019)
>   Swire Pacific-A,(00023) Bank Of East Asia,(00027) Galaxy,(00066) MTR
>   Corp,(00135) Kunlun Energy,(00151) Want Want China,(00175) Geely
>   Auto,(00267) Citic,(00293) Cathay Pacific,(00358) Jiangxi
>   Copper,(00386) Sinopec,(00388) HKEX,(00390) China Railway,(00489)
>   Dongfeng Group,(00494) Li & Fung,(00688) China Overseas,(00700)
>   Tencent,(00728) China Telecom,(00753) Air China,(00762) China
>   Unicom,(00788) China Tower Corporation Limited,(00823) Link
>   REIT,(00857) PetroChina,(00883) CNOOC,(00902) Huaneng Power,(00914)
>   Anhui Conch,(00939) CCB,(00941) China Mobile,(00992) Lenovo
>   Group,(00998) Citic Bank,(01044) Hengan Int'l,(01088) China
>   Shenhua,(01093) CSPC Pharmaceutical,(01099) Sinopharm,(01109) China
>   Res Land,(01113) CK Asset,(01171) Yanzhou Coal,(01186) China Rail
>   Cons,(01211) BYD,(01288) ABC,(01299) AIA,(01336) NCI,(01339) PICC
>   Group,(01359) China Cinda,(01398) ICBC,(01658) PSBC,(01800) China Comm
>   Cons,(01810) XiaoMi Corporation,(01816) CGN Power,(01876) Budweiser
>   APAC,(01898) China Coal,(01918) Sunac,(01928) Sands China,(01988)
>   Minsheng Bank,(02007) Country Garden,(02018) AAC Tech,(02202) China
>   Vanke,(02238) GAC Group,(02282) MGM China,(02318) Ping An,(02319)
>   Mengniu Dairy,(02328) PICC,(02333) Greatwall Motor,(02382) Sunny
>   Opt,(02388) BOCHK,(02600) Chalco,(02601) CPIC,(02628) China
>   Life,(02777) Guangzhou R&F,(02800) Tracker Fund,(02822) CSOP A50
>   ETF,(02823) X iShares A50,(02828) HS H-Share ETF,(02888) Stan
>   Chart,(02899) Zijin Mining,(03188) CAM CSI300 ETF,(03323) CNBM,(03328)
>   BoComm,(03333) China Evergrande Group,(03690) Meituan Dianping,(03888)
>   Kingsoft,(03968) CM Bank,(03988) Bank of China,(06030) Citic
>   Sec,(06837) Haitong Sec,(09988) Alibaba}

---

If you know the code number e.g. 00700 then you can download the CSV with the data.

```
session = StartWebSession[];

(* The code is in the URL *)
WebExecute[session, 
 "OpenPage" -> 
  "https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv.aspx?ucode=00700"];

exportElement = WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "HyperlinkText" -> "Export to CSV"];

WebExecute[session, "ClickElement" -> exportElement]

DeleteObject[session];
```

The file "statistics_hv_iv.csv" is downloaded to your browsers default download directory.

Comment: Rohit, Thanks for your reply and I can now download the CSV file. However, the file extension is with .csv.crdownload (I can just rename it to .csv manually). But some times it will long name such as cee46dbb-fc91-4cec-97e6-8a801ea5b96d.tmp. If I reset the kernal every time, the file will be with .csv.crdownload.

Comment: Usually in Chrome an extension of `crdownload` means that the file download has not completed. Try waiting before executing `DeleteObject[session]`.

Comment: Rohit, I solved the file name problem by adding a Pause[1] command after the url is opened. Then all the file name is normal. Thanks for your help. Alan

Comment: @Akcmok You are welcome. Could you please accept my answer if it is satisfactory or let me know if there is anything missing. Thanks.